# Twitter streaming API - trying to get results based on location/bounding box

Tags: twitter, geolocation, twitter-streaming-api

I am playing around with the Twitter Streaming API and have got my head around it at a basic level, but I can't seem to get reliable results for the location - I'm using a bounding box as specificed in the docs, the location I want to track is Glasgow but I am getting results from all over the world.

My bounding box is $locations = '55.67,-4.66,56.17,-3.892540';
Does anyone know how to get the correct bounding box? If these are correct, then is there another explanation for what might be happening? Thanks!

Comment: You have it in latlon, twitter wants it lonlat.  IOW, try '-4.66,55.67,-3.98,56.17'. BTW, IME, you'll still get tweets outside of the bounding box but hopefully not from China. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have it in latlon, twitter wants it lonlat. IOW, try '-4.66,55.67,-3.98,56.17'. BTW, IME, you'll still get tweets outside of the bounding box but hopefully not from "all over the world". :-)